# RestTemplate POST Image File Request With An auth Token

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-rest

With the following code

```
private def uploadImageFile(assetId: String, apiKey: String, authToken: String, file: MultipartFile, hostUrl: String, restTemplate: RestTemplate): ResponseEntity[util.Map[String, String]] = {

  val assignFileToAssetUrl = s"$hostUrl/..."

  var multipartRequest: MultiValueMap[String, Object] = new LinkedMultiValueMap[String, Object]()
  multipartRequest.add("file", file.getBytes)
  multipartRequest.add("name", "file")
  multipartRequest.add("filename", file.getOriginalFilename)
  multipartRequest.add("apiKey", apiKey)
  multipartRequest.add("authToken", authToken)
  println("Created multipart request: " + multipartRequest)

  var  headers: HttpHeaders= new HttpHeaders()
  headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)

  val request: HttpEntity[Object]  = new HttpEntity[Object](multipartRequest, headers);
  println("request: " + request)

  var messageConverters: util.List[HttpMessageConverter[_]] = new util.ArrayList[HttpMessageConverter[_]]();
  messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
  messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
  restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

  val httpResponse: ResponseEntity[util.Map[String, String]] = restTemplate.postForEntity(assignFileToAssetUrl, multipartRequest, classOf[java.util.Map[String, String]])
  if (!httpResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)){
    println("Problems with the request. Http status: " + httpResponse.getStatusCode());
  }
  httpResponse
}
```

The log file shows

```
2016-07-16 20:47:01.744 DEBUG 4423 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.client.RestTemplate              : Writing [{file=[[B@6abe44a9], name=[file], filename=[TB1YvKKKVXXXXXQXpXXXXXXXXXX-492-660.jpg], apiKey=[...], authToken=[...]}] using [org.springframework.http.converter.FormHttpMessageConverter@230f7e0d]
```

which indicates The FormHttpMessageConverter is used and it yields a 400 error. If I switch the order of the two message converter being added into the list. The log message will show that the MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter is used and it yields a 500 error.

What will be the right way to post an image file along with some other data?

The above code is in Scala. I port Java code into Scala. It shall be under stable for Java people.

Updated:
I make a change based on the answer without a luck. I still get the 400 error. Notice I replace the "authToken" key with "Authorization". The followings is the changed code:

```
 private def assignFileToAsset(assetId: String, apiKey: String, authToken: String, file: MultipartFile, hostUrl: String, restTemplate: RestTemplate): ResponseEntity[util.Map[String, String]] = {

   val assignFileToAssetUrl = s"$hostUrl/..."

   var multipartRequest: MultiValueMap[String, Object] = new LinkedMultiValueMap[String, Object]()
   multipartRequest.add("file", file.getBytes)
   multipartRequest.add("name", "file")
   multipartRequest.add("filename", file.getOriginalFilename)
   println("Created multipart request: " + multipartRequest)

   var  headers: HttpHeaders= new HttpHeaders()
   headers.add("apiKey", apiKey)
   headers.add("Authorization", authToken)
   headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA)

   val request: HttpEntity[Object]  = new HttpEntity[Object](multipartRequest, headers);
   println("request: " + request)
   println("Posting request to: " + assignFileToAssetUrl)

   val httpResponse: ResponseEntity[util.Map[String, String]] = restTemplate.postForEntity(assignFileToAssetUrl, multipartRequest, classOf[java.util.Map[String, String]])
   if (!httpResponse.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)){
     println("Problems with the request. Http status: " + httpResponse.getStatusCode());
   }
   httpResponse
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What I think is you may need to send the access token with the http header and other the parameters and the file content should be sent along the http body. An expected code (not with exact syntax)

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/yourMapping", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String yourMethod(HttpServletRequest request) {

      RestTemplate template = new RestTemplate();
      HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
      headers.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
      headers.add("Authorization", authToken);

      LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object> map =  

                  new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
      map.add("your_param_key", "your_param_value");
      map.add("files", your_file_content_in_byte_array);

      HttpEntity<LinkedMultiValueMap<String, Object>> 

              requestEntity = new HttpEntity<>(map, headers);

      String response = restTemplate.postForObject

 (uploadFilesUrl, requestEntity, String.class);

}
```

Please refer following posts for more info.

http://techie-mixture.blogspot.com/2016/07/authentcation-with-rest-template.html

http://techie-mixture.blogspot.com/2016/07/sending-multipart-files-using-spring.html

Comment: Thanks for your input. Your code essentially is the same as mine other than the message converters. To my knowledge, the default message converter is FormHttpMessageConverter.

Comment: Did you try that ?

Comment: Can you share your applicationContext.xml or any other configurations ?

Comment: I use Spring Boot and nothing in the Java configuration. What configuration might cause the problem?

Comment: Make sure you have an instantiate of multi part file like in any of your configuration <bean id="multipartResolver"
  class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver" />